# How to tell if my router has been hacked?

Tags: security, wireless-router

I've noticed that my home broadband speed seems to be a bit slow in recent days.  I noticed, last night, that my Wireless Router had given a DHCP lease to a public IP address with an odd formation; something like 111.10.11.110.

Should I consider these warning signs of my ZyXEL router being compromised in some way?

Comment: FWIW, that IP address is in China.

Comment: (Do you have a password set on the router?)

Answer (score 1):

First things first, change your passwords and check your configuration settings.

That being said, I don't think it's been compromised, though a lease to a public IP address sounds funny. Perhaps you are mixing up some terms?

Comment: Nope.  There were three items in the DHCP lease list:
192.x.x.a (laptop)
192.x.x.b (DROID)
111.10.11.110 (Crash Override or Acid Burn)